# Android : How Target Layout For specific Dpi Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I Problem With : Huawei 720x1280 pixel 5 inch but 294 dpi !
Please See Picture In This Device :(Huawei Y5II)
[image]

This Is my Layout In Android Studio :
[image]

How Target This Device My Layout ?
I Use Other Res Folder Like : sw320dp and other qualifier Res Folder But Not Work .. 
This Display Information Device :
[image]

I Work Multi Screen Layout Design Before 
I know Rule Of Screen Support Multi Size Like : small Screen large screen and other ..
Please Help Target This Device with 294 dpi and 728x1280pixel 5 inch....
Android studio Can not help me I Test On all Device Profile In IDE show good without problem but on this device with these information Last Button Not Show .
thx .
**Edited :**
This Is My Layout Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:background="#F3F3F3"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lloader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <com.wang.avi.AVLoadingIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/avloader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:indicatorColor="@android:color/black"
            app:indicatorName="BallPulseIndicator" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtloader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="در حال ارسال اطلاعات"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/texttitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="ثبت نام"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/llmain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar1"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lltitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="#248c2f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/titletext"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="اطلاعات را وارد کنید"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llbtns"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lltitle"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <com.libizo.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editusername"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="نام کاربری را وارد کنید"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                        app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                    <com.libizo.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editpassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="گذرواژه را وارد کنید"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                        app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                    <com.libizo.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="نام را وارد کنید"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                        app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        />

                    <com.libizo.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editfamily"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="نام خانوادگی را وارد کنید"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                        app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                    <com.libizo.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edittel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="شماره تماس را وارد کنید"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                        app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

                    <com.libizo.CustomEditText
                        android:id="@+id/editaddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:hint="آدرس را وارد کنید"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#248c2f"
                        app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
                        app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="4dp"
                        app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/llbtns"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn3_gray"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtregister"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="ثبت نام"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgregister"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Button is RelativeLayout :

```
            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/llbtns"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn3_gray"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtregister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="ثبت نام"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgregister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please add the layout in code and make explicit which is the problem. I am guessing it is the button at the bottom but I shouldn't be guessing.

Comment: @Juan thx . I Update My Post . Please Review .My Problem Is Clear : Last Green Botton Is not Show Correctly In Huawei Y5II 294 ppi Density .

Comment: You should be using constraintlayout not relativelayout if you want screen size specific sizing, is there any reason you're using relativelayout? @zobydehkarimi since you've put your last button as relatively below your linearlayout it is displaying but out of screen as it is pushed by linearlayout. Try wrapping your xml in a scrollview

Comment: @kkarakk NO Special Reason . But This My Design Get From Designer Of My Team . I Not Problem With Any Device . But Problem With Device . I can not Change  Design . I Want Solve Problem On This Device And Other 249ppi Density With Same size .I Want Separate Layout File For This Specific Model Device .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You kkarakk.
I Wrapped Into ScrollView And My Problem Solved .
Thx .
Result Picture :
[image]